# SQL order updates on table - show differences on a daily report

Tags: sql, self-join

Long story short, I've been trying to generate a script to show the last days orders
which might be updates on previous entered orders.
Example order *00022 previous qty entry was 42 and todays update on the order was 18.
Ideally I would run this will run daily and it would show me orders changed.

| ID | CreatedOn | OrderNO | OrderQty | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 126944 | 2021-10-01 14:10:00.4220000 | 0000000022 | 32.000 | F |
| 126945 | 2021-10-04 15:11:00.4100000 | 0000000022 | 42.000 | F |
| 126946 | 2021-10-05 07:53:01.7700000 | 0000000024 | 6.000 | F |
| 126948 | 2021-10-05 08:30:01.8160000 | 0000000024 | 10.000 | F |
| 126947 | 2021-10-05 08:13:01.6990000 | 0000000024 | 6.000 | F |
| 126948 | 2021-10-05 08:30:01.8160000 | 0000000024 | 10.000 | F |
| 126959 | 2021-10-05 09:13:01.4330000 | 0000000026 | 5.000 | F |
| 126997 | 2021-10-06 12:30:03.6190000 | 0000000022 | 18.000 | F |

Result wanted

| ID | CreatedOn | OrderNO | OrderQty | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 126944 | 2021-10-01 14:10:00.4220000 | 0000000022 | 32.000 | F |
| 126945 | 2021-10-04 15:11:00.4100000 | 0000000022 | 42.000 | F |
| 126997 | 2021-10-06 12:30:03.6190000 | 0000000022 | 18.000 | F |

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images (or links to them.) Also show us your current query attempt. I.e. [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Basically grabbing any changes made today into a temp table. Then putting the last change to the same order in another temp table and comparing the result.

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CreatedOn DESC PARTITION BY OrderNO) [RowNum],
    Id,
    OrderNO,
    OrderQty,
    CreatedOn
INTO #tempGrouped
FROM
    [table]

SELECT
    * --Replace this with all the column names
INTO #tempToday
FROM
    #tempGrouped
WHERE
    RowNum = 1
    AND CONVERT(DATE, CreatedOn) = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE())

SELECT 
    g.* --Replace with columns
INTO #tempLastChange
FROM
   #tempToday [t]
   JOIN #tempGrouped [g] ON g.OrderNO = t.OrderNO
       AND g.RowNum = 2

SELECT
    l.OrderNO [Order Number],
    l.OrderQty [Old Quantity],
    t.OrderQty [Updated Order Quantity]
FROM
    #tempToday [t]
    JOIN #tempLastChange [l] ON l.OrderNO = t.OrderNO

DROP TABLE #tempGrouped
DROP TABLE #tempToday
DROP TABLE #tempLastChange
```

Comment: That looks promising but I was looking for something that does not involve creating tables. Thanks